# ColdFusion 10 REST API: Change JSON response after serialization

Tags: json, rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When using ColdFusion 10's new REST API, how can I pipe into the response pipeline so that I can change the JSON response after it's been serialized by ColdFusion 10's REST API?

For example, let's say I have the following end-point:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/widgets" produces="application/json">

    <cffunction name="getWidget" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" restpath="{id}" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="id" required="true" restargsource="path" type="numeric"/>

        <cfreturn {
            id = arguments.id,
            code = "string:.10"
        } />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

After this method returns (i.e. after ColdFusion creates the JSON response by using SerializeJSON), I'd like to replace "string:" with an empty string.  I tried to do this (with the technique described here: http://house-of-fusion.10909.n7.nabble.com/getPageContext-in-onRequestEnd-is-empty-td78578.html) but I wasn't able to change the response.  Anyone know how I can change the response?

**Background:**

The reason why I'm looking for such a hack is because SerializeJSON (the default serialization that CF 10 REST API uses) would treat **code = ".10"** as a float and render **"code":0.1**, which is not what I want. This problem is well documented, but a solution to overcome this while using the native REST API doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: have you tried returnformat="plain" and return the desired JSON string yourself?  Not sure if this workaround would work for REST but it worked for ajax

Comment: I'd do what Henry says. Create the JSON string yourself and use returnformat=plain.

Comment: @RaymondCamden, does this mean that there's no way to pipe into the response pipeline after JSON serialization happens?  It would be really unfortunate if I need to use Henry's technique for every API end-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to tap into ColdFusion's response pipeline to edit the response body produced by ColdFusion 10's REST API. However, for IIS users, you can use HttpModules for this.  You need to write the HttpModule in .NET, but it's pretty simple.  I wrote a couple of HttpModules to post-process ColdFusion's response and the source code is available here:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process

If you're trying to solve the same problem that I identified in this question, you can use the HttpModule that I posted here:

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process/blob/master/JsonStringCleanserModule.cs

To plug it into your application, you can follow these steps:

**1) Grab the ready to use DLL:**

https://github.com/johnnyoshika/coldfusion-rest-post-process/tree/master/bin/Release

Grab the `ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.dll` file from that URL and drop it into the bin folder of your ColdFusion application

For example, if your ColdFusion application is here:

```
C:/myapp
```

Then you want to put the dll here:

```
C:/myapp/bin/ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.dll
```

If you don't want to trust a stranger's DLL, you'll need to review the source code and compile the project in Visual Studio yourself to generate the DLL.

**2) Modify web.config**

Modify or create the the web.config file in the root of your application. The content should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <!-- This is for IIS5, IIS6, and IIS7 Classic -->
            <add name="JsonStringCleanserModule" type="ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.JsonStringCleanserModule"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <!-- This is for IIS7+ Integrated mode -->
            <add name="JsonStringCleanserModule" type="ColdFusion.RestPostProcess.JsonStringCleanserModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**3) Prepend Strings with `***string***:`

Whenever you want to output strings in your JSON, prepend the value with `***string***:`. For example:

```
<cffunction name="getWidget" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" restpath="{id}" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="id" required="true" restargsource="path" type="numeric"/>

    <cfreturn {
        id = arguments.id,
        code = "***string***:.10"
    } />
</cffunction>
```

That should do it.  Adding the `***string***:` forces ColdFusion to serialize the value as a string, then the HttpModule will remove all instances of `***string***:` so the final output will be:

```
{"id":1,"code":".10"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom response described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-7fec.html)

You serialize your data to json yourself, change the string and set it as content on response. In short the code inside function would look like this:

```
<cfset response=structNew()>
<cfset response.status=201>
<cfset var content = SerializeJSON(data)>
<!--- change the content string --->
<cfset response.content= content>
<cfset response.headers=structNew()> 
<cfset restSetResponse( response )>
```

HTH.